# Does anyone know free C++ assessment tests online?

Tags: c++

Does anyone know of free C++ assessment tests?

I would like to practice my C++ skils before interviews. Brainbench used to have it for free; now they want $49.99 and I think it's rip off..

Answer (score 10):

Most of those "C++ questions" and pay-for-view packets are a ripoff and often a scam.

If you are interviewing at a big company, explicitly Google their name and c++ interview questions. Enough people post the interview questions online, and these companies are way too lazy to actually change this question set. Examples include Google, Bloomberg, and others.

If you want to ace interviews that ask about c++ corner cases, consider the c++ faq or the C++ faq lite (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/). It's not questions, but it's the most valuable C++ resource IMHO.

And if you don't use C++ on a day to day basis, try to write some code and compile. I was humbled after too many years of Java to see how much of the syntax is no longer natural to me.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to try My CPP Quiz as that has a set of very comprehensive C++ questions. If you can get through those easily you could consider yourself having a satisfactory understanding of basic C++.

http://www.mycppquiz.com

Comment: In the question: "3.3.6/3 says if reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid program the program is ill-formed. In this case the enum SIZE is not in scope when array is declared making the array size 5. However if the members were reordered to declare array after the definition of the enum the array size would be 3. Thus since reordering member declaration changes the program, it is undefined."

The text says the correct answer is 5, but then that the program is undefined (if reordered). Yet the 'correct' answer is undefined, but that is only if a re-order is done?

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of algorithmic problems to solve at SPOJ. Some of them are straightforward, well known algorithms implementations (see also [The Problems classifier](http://problemclassifier.appspot.com/)) some are harder. The online judge service will check your code's correctness online.